# Save workbook fails

Tags: excel, vba

This code works sometimes does not work sometimes.
my system is synced with onedrive is this the reason. Path here is a local path.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add

wb.SaveAs Filename:=Path & name
wb.Close True
```

runtime error

> method save as object _workbook failed

I also tried `wb.SaveAs Filename:=Path & name, FileFormat:=1` as suggested by Microsoft in [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/error-message-when-you-run-a-visual-basic-for-applications-macro-in-excel-method-saveas-of-object-worksheet-failed-376fcbb2-9941-f34d-1aba-ca602903245f).

Comment: Is path a valid folder? Is there a folderseparator between path and name missing ( \ )?

Comment: Please close the workbook instance before closing the workbook.

Comment: @nishitdey `wb.Close` does close the workbook. I don't get your comment.

Comment: Try these methods 1) CLose the actual workbook and then try to run this code.. if the code is in the same workbook you can use "Save as method" or "Save" method.

Comment: @nishitdey no he is trying to save a new added workbook. So he can't close it because it was not saved yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it has do do with OneDrive and not with your code (at least if your file path/name is correct). You can use error handling to get an error message and check if the path/file is the correct one in case of an error.

```
On Error Resume Next
wb.SaveAs Filename:=Path & name
If Err.Number Then
    MsgBox "File """ & Path & name & """ could not be saved.".
    Debug.Print Path & name
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error Goto 0  ' re-activate error reporting!

wb.Close False
```

Now you can check if the file path and file name is correct.

Also note that `wb.Close True` makes your file beeing saved twice in a row! First with `.SaveAs` and second with the `SaveChanges:=True` parameter of `.Close`. So it will take double the time and is usless to save a file twice in a row in the same file.

Comment: Yes, the problem is with one drive path. It does not occur when I am disconnected. looks like macros is the thing of the past now it is all office scripts?

Answer (score -1):

It should be something like this

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim Path as String

Set wb = Workbooks.Add

Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & custom_name & ".xlsm"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=Path, FileFormat:=51

fileName = custom_name
```

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` saves the `ActiveWorkbook` not the new added workbook `wb`. Always fully reference the workbook and avoid using `ActiveWorkbook`. • And `ActiveWorkbook.Path` will fail because the active workbook after adding a workbook has no path as it was not saved yet. You can use `ThisWorkbook.Path` if you want to save it in the same path as the workbook the code is running in.